# Database abstraction schema manually without ORM

Tags: php, mysql, orm

I'm in the following standardsituation: I have two model objects from class ShippingGroup and Shipping where Shipping is a child of ShippingGroup. ShippingGroup->shippings holds the kids as usual. In the mySql database I have the following entities:

[image: Simple case]

I deal with those situations now for quite a long time every now and then and always have this doubt to not doing it right when it comes to CRUD. Creat, read, delete is of course easy, but update is not. In my opinion.

I know I could use an **ORM** and did it already but I'm not really satisfied by the solutions out there (tried doctrine and redbeans) and want to do manually to have influence on design and performance.

Would anyone please be so kind an post an example for one-to-many, many-to-one and many-to-many relationships? Or at least hint me a free resource like a blog-post or something.

Thank you!

*My usual approach:*

```
if (!is_object($shipping_group) ||
        get_class($shipping_group) != "ShippingGroup" ||
        $shipping_group->shipping_group_id === NULL) return;

    global $db;

    $sql = "UPDATE ShippingGroups SET label={$shipping_group->label} WHERE shipping_group_id={$shipping_group->shipping_group_id};";

    if ($db->query($sql)) {

        // shippings

        $childs_old = array();
        $childs_new = array();

        foreach ($shipping_group->shippings as $shipping) {

            if ($shipping->shipping_id === NULL) {
                $childs_new[$shipping->shipping_id] = $shipping;
            } else {
                $childs_old[$shipping->shipping_id] = $shipping;
            }
        }


        $sql = "SELECT shipping_id FROM Shippings WHERE shipping_group_id={$shipping_group->shipping_group_id};";

        if ($db_shippings = $db->query($sql)) {

            while ($row = $db_shippings->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

                $shipping_id = $row['shipping_id'];

                if (isset($childs_old[$shipping_id])) {
                    $this->update_shipping($childs_new[$shipping_id]);
                } elseif (isset($childs_new[$shipping_id]) {
                    $this->create_shipping($childs_new[$shipping_id]);
                } else {
                    $this->delete_shipping($childs_new[$shipping_id]);
                    // $db->query("DELETE FROM Shippings WHERE shipping_id={$shipping_id}");
                }

            }
        }


    }



}
```

Comment: If you're serious about developing applications, you really need to invest in learning a framework like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). There are many out there of varying quality, but the majority of them offer some kind of ORM solution that makes your life easier. If the two you've tried don't fit your style and needs, that's okay, but don't give up on ORMs completely because of that. Just because you tried two pairs of pants in a row that didn't fit doesn't mean you should go naked.

Comment: What about updates is giving you issues. (And FWIW, I rarely use ORMs either. I just don't like the indirect control.)

Comment: @mrunion Added my approach to the post. I do this when it come to updating in an one-to-many relationship. But I don't find it very elegant.

Comment: @tadman As said above, I like to have influence on design and performance. In an ORM concept this is not possible.

Comment: You're completely missing the point of an ORM. If you don't use one, you'll end up writing your own, and I assure you, unless you've written *several* that are in large-scale use, you'll get it wrong. Most ORMs make your life considerably easier, and if on occasion, for performance reasons, you need to bypass them, they give you options. Laravel, as an example, gives you direct access without any hesitation, but doesn't *require* you to use that. What you've got here is riddled with SQL injection bugs. Using a framework properly avoids that.

Comment: @tadman Sorry, maybe you're right. But as long as I'm not convinced I will stay with the best one: Plain SQL. In my opinion a bad ORM is a lot more bad than bad SQL. SQL injection was not considered here.

Comment: It's the "oh, I hadn't considered that" part of slamming away with low-level PHP that bites everyone eventually. A framework does more than give you an ORM. It gives you XSS protection, a coherent, maintainable structure to start with, and as the framework is improved, you reap the benefits by upgrading to a newer version. Find one that suits your style and needs. If PHP doesn't feel right, don't forget there's Node.js, Python, Ruby, and others as well.

Comment: @tadman okay, that won't get us anywhere. Back to my question: How would you do an update in that one-to-many situation?

Comment: You haven't given enough information to answer that question. There's a lot of code there, but it all refers to functions that are of unknown composition. Generally if you want to do a mass update you need to read in all the existing records, reconcile with the data you know you want to commit, split into a series of delete, update and insert operations, and run those inside a transaction, rescuing from any errors accordingly. You say you're opposed to ORMs, but a good one will get you 90% of the way there if you use the right tools. Otherwise you'll have to write all that yourself.

Comment: This is what I thought: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/06/object-relational-mapping-is-the-vietnam-of-computer-science.html
Maybe the simple situations are enough for your usecases. But if it becomes a bit more complicated, ORMs suffer. And I don't want to learn/use several of them to proof that.